# mongod Windows service utilizes the most I/O write bytes. Is it really a harmful?

Tags: mongodb

All started with this - my Windows 8.1 got very slow and shows 100% disk usage:

[image]

I started digging what's going on and found this - mongod.exe (which is running as a Windows service) utilizes the most I/O write bytes:

[image]

And it is just after Windows start. No any other programs are running. Only Windows Task Manager in order to look at I/O operations.

I don't know if it is the reason my system is slow, but want to know why mongod.exe does so and if it is indeed the reason how to solve it. And I want to continue using mongod as a windows service.

Comment: do you have any incoming connections to mongod?

Answer (score 0):

`mongod.exe` is the service for the MongoDB database. It seems that you're running a database on your computer and querying it heavily. If this is the case, then you can't really avoid high disk usage, since the database is stored on the disk.

If you must run the database, and you want to speed up your computer, I would recommend upgrading your hard drive to an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb high disk operation caused by frequently disk operation. Here is one link
[mongodb_low_memory_high_disk_io](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/6060427),

> Move to SSD could be one option. However, it could depend on data. since MongoDB index buckets are 8k, you will never want to set readahead below 16 anyway, or it will take 2 disk accesses to read in one index bucket. A general good practice is to start with your current setting, halve it, then re-assess your RAM utilization and IO and move on from there.